# Storing 4x 0-16 numbers in a short (or 2 numbers in a byte)

Tags: c#, hex, pack

I'm packing some binary data as a short, but want to have 4x values of 0-F.. And would like to do this without having a bunch of switch() cases reading the string.split of a hex

Someone have a clever, elegant solution for this or should I just long-hand it?

eg; `1C4A = (1, 12, 4, 10)`

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far.

Comment: Title specifies 2x numbers in a byte. Body specifies 4x numbers in a short. Please correct one of them.

Comment: If you wanted two bytes I would have said go for `ExplicitLayout` on a struct, but you can't do that on base16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift in and out

```
var a = 1;
var b = 12;
var c = 4;
var d = 10;

// in
var packed = (short) ((a << 12) | (b << 8) | (c << 4) | d);

// out
a = (packed >> 12) & 0xf;
b = (packed >> 8) & 0xf;
c = (packed >> 4) & 0xf;
d = packed & 0xF;

Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.WriteLine(b);
Console.WriteLine(c);
Console.WriteLine(d);
```

**Output**

```
1
12
4
10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can shift by 4 (or divide and multiply by 16) to move numbers into different place values. Then mask and shift your packed number to get your original numbers back.

Eg if you want to store 1 and 2 you could do:

```
int packed = (1 << 4) + 2;
int v1 = (packed & 0xF0) >> 4;
int v2 = packed & 0x0F;

Console.WriteLine($"{v1}, {v2}");
>>> 1, 2
```